# How can I assign cart items variable list to items coming from Firestore using Map?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have a cart and I want to assign my cart items to my _items variable inside my Provider. This is my method. I don't know if I should use toJson() or fromJson() methods:

This is the variable and the function inside the provider:

```
Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
void getItems()async {
    var newItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("Cart").get();
    _items = newItems; // The error occurs here
}
```

> A value of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, CartItem>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, CartItem>'.

```
CartModel.dart

class CartItem {
  String? id;
  String? title;
  String? price;
  int? qty;
  String? image;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.qty,
    required this.image,
  });

  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    price = json['price'];
    qty = json['qty'] as int;
    // totalprice = double.parse(json['totalprice']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['qty'] = this.qty;
    // data['totalprice'] = this.totalprice;

    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned result from `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId).collection("Cart").get()` is a [**`QuerySnapshot`**](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) which cannot be assigned to the `Map<String, CartItem>` variable directly.

You need to convert the `QuerySnapshot` retrieved from the Firestore into a Map<String, CartItem> object. You can use the `fromJson` method of the `CartItem` class to convert each document in the `QuerySnapshot` to a `CartItem` object and then add it to the `_items` map.

Here’s the updated code which will do the above conversion and print the  `_items` map to the console on press of button:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
  void getItems() async {
    var newItems = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc("pPwFKDJupSQVfl87Ddof75Wk3vM2") //any user Id
        .collection("cart")
        .get();
    newItems.docs.forEach((doc) {
      var cartItem = CartItem.fromJson(doc.data());
      _items[doc.id] = cartItem;
    });
    for (var entry in _items.entries) {
      var itemId = entry.key;
      var item = entry.value;
      print("------------------------------");
      print('Item ID: $itemId');
      print('Title: ${item.title}');
      print('Price: ${item.price}');
      print('Quantity: ${item.qty}');
      print('Image: ${item.image}');
      print("------------------------------");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: getItems,
          child: const Text("Press me"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```